# Deploy vue.js app in a sub directory

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I've built a vue.js app using `vue-cli 3.0` and everything is great.

Now I'm wanting to deploy it into production, but I need to deploy it into a sub folder, not the root, i.e.:

https://example.com/myvueapp/*

I've built the production distribution with `npm run build` but the problem is that the links to the .js files etc are all `/js/vendor.9e469b3e.js`. How would I make this `/myvueapp/js/vendor.9e469b3e.js`?

I've found other answers that say "change the webpack config file". But I don't have a webpack config file anywhere I can see?

[image]

Comment: You should have webpack as your bundler, so there should be webpack config somewhere over there. Try to look for production webpack build and in output property set the path where you want to generate the production files.

Answer (score 5):

Using vue-cli 3 you can set the base URL in the vue.config.js file. It would look something like this

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  baseUrl: 'myvueapp',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Would you set production/dev environments using the normal `.env.production` config files?